# Scheduled emails with Azure

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

This should be a very straight forward question, but I can't find an answer.

Right now I have a windows service that uses a timer to kick off scheduled emails and do other scheduled tasks. What's the best way to do the equivalent with Azure?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can run a background thread, launched from your Run(), that does nothing but sleep for a while and then execute some scheduled-email code.

Alternatively, you can make this task queue-driven, and place a queue message with an initial invisibility timeout set (so that the queue message won't be retrievable until a certain time period elapses.

In either case, you'll want to use an external SMTP service. SendGrid just announced a free tier for Windows Azure users, along with supporting libraries. See details about this [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/windowsazure/archive/2012/01/25/announcing-native-windows-azure-libraries-and-special-free-pricing-using-sendgrid-for-windows-azure-customers.aspx).

Comment: It doesn't matter whether you use a worker or web role. They're both Windows 2008 Server virtual machines (the only significant difference being the web role starts IIS, while the worker role doesn't). Since you have to run a minimum of one instance of each role, it may be more economical to run the email scheduler in the background of your web role. If you have other background tasks, combined with massive email traffic, it makes sense to have a separate worker role from your web role, for scaling purposes.

Comment: Thanks, does that mean since it's a full 2008 VM, I can just install my service on it as is?

Comment: You *can* install your service as-is. However, this is more complicated than just calling your core code from the `Run()` method. With a Windows Service, you're responsible for getting it installed, setting up appropriate security, etc. You can see [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mwasham/archive/2011/04/21/10147957.aspx) to get an idea of what it takes.